# Inserting new row in table with jQuery and increasing array count

Tags: php, jquery

So I'm adding a row to a html table. I have a checkbox in the row so I need to increase the array key of the inputs I'm adding so I can check if the checkbox is set or not. This is the html

```
<tr>
   <td><img src="/pics/deleteRow.png" class="delete"> </td>
   <td class="productColumn">

   <select name="productInputName[<?php echo $rowNum; ?>]" class="productSelect" >
     <option></option>
     <?php
     foreach($productList as $product){
        //Get options
      }
      ?>
     </select>

      </td>
      <td><input class="quantityField" name="quantity[<?php echo $rowNum; ?>]"type="number" <?php echo ' value="',$detail->getQuantity(),'"';   ?>></td>
      <td><input class="quantityReturnedField" name="quantityReturned[<?php echo $rowNum; ?>]" type="number" <?php echo ' value="',$detail->getQuantityReturned(),'"';   ?>></td>
      <td> <input class="priceField" name="price[<?php echo $rowNum; ?>]" type="number" step="any"
             <?php echo ' value="', $detail->getPrice(), '"'; ?>></td>
      <td ><input class="subtotalField" type="number" step="any" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td ><input class="specialOrder" type="checkbox" name="specialOrder[<?php echo $rowNum; ?>]" <?php if($detail->getSpecialOrder()){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>>Special Order</td>

 </tr>
```

This is the jQuery

```
var rowNum = 300;

$('.productSelect').change(function() {
    insertBlankRow(1);
});

function insertBlankRow(numRows){
    for(i=0;i < numRows; i++){
        $('#orderTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#orderTable tbody>tr:last').end()
            .find("input[type=checkbox]").attr('name', "specialOrder[" +rowNum + "]").end()
            .find(".productSelect").val("").attr('name', "productInputName[" +rowNum + "]").end()
            .find(".quantityField").val("").attr('name', "quantity["+rowNum+"]");

        rowNum++;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I've gone over this and over this and to my mind it should work but in reality it just copies the index number from the last row for all except the Special Order checkbox where I get a NaN for the index. I've changed the name in the jQuery to no affect so it inserts the row correctly but fails to make any changes to the name attribute. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me when I use this with the table you are using. It adds a row with the index of 301, and then another with 302, and another with 303. ( I filled it out a little 'cause not seeing all fields with the same index bothered me.

```
var rowNum = 300;

$('.productSelect').change(function() {
   insertBlankRow(1);
});

function insertBlankRow(numRows){

    for(i=0;i < numRows; i++){

        $('#orderTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#orderTable tbody>tr:last').end()
        .find(".quantityField").val("").attr('name', "quantity["+rowNum+"]").end()
        .find(".quantityReturnedField").val("").attr('name', "quantityReturned["+rowNum+"]").end()
        .find(".priceField").val("").attr('name', "price["+rowNum+"]").end()
        .find(".productSelect").val("").attr('name', "productInputName["+rowNum+"]").end()
        .find("input[type=checkbox]").attr('name', "specialOrder[" +rowNum + "]");
        rowNum++;
    }

    return false;
}
```

See uploaded test here: http://www.davideugenepratt.com/stack-overflow-samples/add-row-to-table.html

Comment: Sorry I should have had that in there. I've edited it to reflect the rowNum declaration

Comment: Ok, so I'm stupid. I was calling the wrong js file. +1 for showing the code worked and forcing me to look elsewhere for the problem. Sorry to have wasted your time :(